# C#: Timeout does not match elapsed time

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeoutexception

I have an application that connects to a service (webserviceSoap1), and that service has the next timeout configuration:

```
<binding name="webserviceSoap1" 
         openTimeout="00:10:00" 
         closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:10:00"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
```

From what I understand, I'm stating here that all timeouts have to wait at least 10 minutes to end communication and get a **System.TimeoutException**. However, **here is the issue I'm not understanding**. After around 2-3 minutes, i get a TimeoutException saying that the program waited for a response almost ten minutes (which is not possible), and in the same place, it says the elapsed time was around two minutes

[image: Timeout exception says it waited almost 10 minutes, but elapsed time is around two minutes]

**Why the gap of time? Am I configuring the binding values correctly?**

If I change the values of the timeouts to "10:00:00" it will complete the process correctly. However, still using "01:00:00", which I understand is an hour, the process breaks after 4 minutes saying that it waited "00:59:59.16472" before sending the TimeoutException.

Comment: can you please upload your code?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I'm unable to share the code (it belongs to my company). What i would like to know is if the issue is normal. Is this something that happens or is a sign of a bad configuration in the IIS or in my web.config?

I know that without the code is almost like guessing, but any clue can help me to find the correct path.

Comment: If you can't share the code, boil it down to a stand-alone [mcve]. In the process, you may find the problem yourself (in which case you can post the answer). If you can't find it, share the MCVE (there should be no problem sharing that, since it would have nothing specifically valuable in it), so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was located within the Load Balancer that was managing the connection of the client to the server. Both the client and the service were configured to wait 10 minutes of timeout. However, the Load Balancer had only one minute, and that's why the timeout was arising sooner than expected.

I ask the administrators of the Load Balancer to change it to 10 minutes and everything is working as expected.

However, the way the timeout is reported to the client is very misleading, since it states that the set timeout has already reached to the limit, when this is not true.

Also, the way the Load Balancer manages the interruption of the service can be misleading, since in my case, the Load Balancer (F5) would wait until the service returns a response, and then, it would interrupt the response, arising its own timeout error. As a result, the client only receives the notice of the reached timeout. Also, the client will not get this error in one minute (set by the load balancer), nor in 10 minutes (set by the service), but at the time the service returns the response.

I hope this helps to anyone getting a similar behavior.